# Find Last Modifcation Time of Filegroup Option in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, filegroup

I searched almost everywhere but I couldn't find a solution.
I'm looking for a way to find the last time that user change an option of a filegroup in SQL Server database.
For example, the last time of changing read-only property of a specific filegroup.

Is there any way?

Thanks :)

Comment: If it's not in `sys.filegroups` (and it's not), it's safe to say the engine doesn't track this kind of information. You can try getting some data from the default trace/`event_health`/error logs, though there's no guarantee it's in there, and if the change goes back long enough it certainly won't be in there. See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48053/97345) for more details on that. If you need this information proactively (that is, you're not hunting for it now but you'd like to know in the future) you could set up a trace (profiler or extended event) for any `ALTER DATABASE`.

Comment: This is where auditing comes into place. SQL Server has a couple of ways to do this, like change data capture, and you could also create a custom trigger to write to a log file or table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments, SQL Server Audit Log solved my problem.

These link about SQL Server Auditing were helpful for me:
Setup SQL Server Audit:
https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-setup-and-use-sql-server-audit-feature/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Read SQL Server Audit Information: 
https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/analyze-and-read-sql-server-audit-information/